# How can I fill an array with Java's for-each loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218004/) earlier attempting to find an error in my code, and the main problem was that I had used a for each loop incorrectly.  I'm new to Java and was wondering why what I had attempted was incorrect and if there would be any possible way of doing the task with a for each loop.

```
public Dids(String thing)
{
    letters= new char[thing.length()];  
    for(char i: letters){
        letters[i] = thing.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

My thought was that since I had declared the size of the array before the loops, that I would be able to iterate through it.

Comment: you're using the letter at each location as an index... it's all twisted round. :-)  You probably mean for(int i = 0; i < thing.length(); i++) letters[i] = thing.charAt(i);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple java question regarding arrays/strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218004/simple-java-question-regarding-arrays-strings)

Comment: Your question was answered pretty thoroughly the first time. If you need clarification, please post a comment to the answer you accepted.

Comment: This is a question specifically pertaining to the foreach loop,  I had  stated in my question that I in fact had asked a question before and was relating this new question to the previous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With foreach constructs, there is no counter for the current index, just the value at the index. The variable 'i' is the value at the current point in the array.

You can do this with an ordinary for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
   letters[i] = thing.charAt(i);
```

Or more concisely,

```
char[] letters = thing.toCharArray();
```

See [String.toCharArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable 'i' takes the value of each char in 'letters'. It's not an index, so letters[i] does not really make any sense.

The 'foreach' construct over a collection only really helps over a traditional for loop if you need to take action based on the value of each element in the collection. If you also need to use the indexes in the collection, a traditional for loop will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a String to a character array ( which is what it seems like you want to do ), just use [String#toCharArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

```
char[] letters = thing.toCharArray();
```